# How to add CSS inline in Vaadin?

Tags: java, css, vaadin

Is it possible to add inline CSS code programmatically?

Like, I have defined a CSS separator like this:

```
.hr{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Now I sometimes want to have it in a different color or a different size.
Would I have to create further `.hr-black`, `.hr-blue` css styles and apply them separately by `.addStyleName()`? Or can I somehow set the color programmatically?

Comment: Separate css, with code only accessing style names, is a default approach in Vaadin. You can use [CSSInject addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/cssinject) to apply styles through code. AFAIK, there is no inbuilt way to access component styling programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can only change CSS at specific component using `component.addStyleName()`, but you can use it dynamically, like this:

```
if (condition)
   component.addStyleName("black");
else
   component.addStyleName("blue")
```